# Why do we have both "ussr" and "soviet union" as tags? Can we merge them?

Tags: support, tags

As you now know, there are two distinct tags, one labeled [soviet-union](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soviet-union) and the other [ussr](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ussr). Given that the latter stands for "Union of Soviet Socialist Republics", I propose to merge them, perhaps making one a synonym of the other.

Otherwise we could as well create independent tags for "cccp", "usa" and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that anyone with a score of 5 or more on a tag can propose making it a synonym through the regular interface. Sadly, I'm not one of those people for [ussr](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ussr). I did have enough to do it on the [soviet-union](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soviet-union) tag, so I've made the proposal there.

Hopefully this is an equal relationship, rather than a request to ditch that one tag in favor of [ussr](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ussr). The content of the [soviet-union](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soviet-union) is frankly awesome, plus I think the term is better than using the acronym, so if I had my druthers I'd keep [soviet-union](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soviet-union) as the main.

Comment: It looks like @YannisRizos is the only user with 5 rep on [tag:ussr]

Comment: There are quite a few users with enough rep on [Soviet Union] (myself not being one of them). I (also) think [Soviet Union] should be the master.