# Can we synonymize the 'soviet-union' and 'soviet' tags?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I noticed that both the [soviet-union](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soviet-union) and [soviet](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soviet) tags exist. I propose we synonymize them, keeping the [soviet-union](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soviet-union) tag, in line with the result of [Why do we have both "ussr" and "soviet union" as tags? Can we merge them?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362/why-do-we-have-both-ussr-and-soviet-union-as-tags-can-we-merge-them)

Answer (score -2):

The Soviet Union has been created in 1922, Soviet Russia - in 1917. This is 5 years of intensive history events. One can tag "soviet" and "russia" which would cover these 5 years.

But this leads to a question why should we combine them? Should then one use "soviet" to mark "Soviet Union" and "soviet"+"russia" to make 1917-1922 part accessible?

What about [Limerick Soviet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerick_Soviet)? Should [Bavaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_Council_Republic) also apply?

In my opinion it is better as it is now.

Comment: By this logic, all (3) questions currently tagged "soviet" should be retagged "soviet-union" (at which point "soviet" will disappear if nobody uses it for a while).

Comment: @T.E.D. - Huh. ... This has been pending for a year+ ... What are we going to do about this? If anything...